# Error unpacking field 35 in ISO 8583 message using jpos

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I am facing problems in splitting up DE 35  my packager xml for DE 35 looks like this.

DE 35 data looks like this
[ 374622441715101175D26071361916993999999F ]
In which 37 is a length and rest of the data.

when i unpacked this field i getting data till second last digit looks like[374622441715005175D23071261916092999999]
F goes to next field. because of this remaining fields are not gets data correctly.

so can you help me to read DE-35 correctly with all data including F .

Comment: Unless i'm counting wrong, it looks to me like the 37th character is the 9, so the f isn't part of the 37 length content, no?

Comment: We could help better if you provide the entire message hex dump (provided there is no sensitive information in there, I'm also assuming that 4622441715005175 is not a real card number, in which case that card should be considered compromised). And your entire package definition so we can reproduce the complete unpacking process.

Comment: Looks like an hex representation of the content and should be handled with IFB_LLNUM. The right 'F' is just the default right padding for the field.

Comment: [02003020058020C010040010000000000550800000830021000100374622441715005175D23071261916092999999F313233343536373831323334353637382020202020202000000000000000000006303030303139] this is my hex dumb

Comment: I tried IFB_LLNUM but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used raw data instead of hex dumb then its working